# Skip UCB iOS build package updates

Tags: ios, json.net, unity-cloud-build

During the iOS build at the UCB, the 'com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json' package is updated from version 3.0.2 to 3.2.0. It breaks down our application because JSONs are not deserialized anymore. Is there a way to skip package updates?

Log:

> [2023-09-05T11:31:43Z - Unity] The following packages were updated:
> [2023-09-05T11:31:43Z - Unity] com.unity.collab-proxy from version
> 1.17.7 to 2.0.4
> **[2023-09-05T11:31:43Z - Unity] com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json from version 3.0.2 to 3.2.0** [2023-09-05T11:31:43Z - Unity]
> com.unity.ide.rider from version 3.0.17 to 3.0.21
> [2023-09-05T11:31:43Z - Unity] com.unity.ide.visualstudio from version
> 2.0.17 to 2.0.18

Find a way to skip update packages in UCB iOS build.